# get real imageview cordinates from touch event

Tags: java, android, uiimageview, imageview, rect

How to convert my real coordinates of image to coordinates that I got from `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event`.basically, I have imageview that I draw rectangles into it and I want to check that user touch inside of these rectangles.
i have somthing like this:

private ArrayList rects = new ArrayList<>();

```
resultView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            for (Rect rect : rects) {
                if (x > rect.left && x < rect.right && y > rect.bottom && 
                y < rect.top) {
                      // the user toches on of these rectangle
                }
             }
        }
        return true;
    }
    });
```

but the real problem is that my `rects` is real image coordinates that is much bigger and the `x , y` is the coordinates of the imageview.how to convert theme.

Answer (score 0):

Since the coordinates coming from the `TouchEvent` are absolute coordinates, you can subtract absolute coordinates of your `ImageView` from them. This will make your `(x,y)` coordinates relative to `ImageView`. You can do it like -

```
int arr[] = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationOnScreen(arr);
float xRelative = event.getRawX() - arr[0];
float yRelative = event.getRawY() - arr[1];
```

You can now use `xRelative` and `yRelative` instead of `x` and `y` given that `rects` contain coordinates relative to your `imageview`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your problem but I think you should add the image view coordinates to the if statement like the following

```
 if (x +resultView.getX() > rect.left && x +resultView.getX()< rect.right  && y +resultView.getY()< rect.bottom && 
            y +resultView.getY()> rect.top )
```